# Windows Service Enterprise Library Data Access Application Blocks Connection Pooling Issue

Tags: c#-4.0, sql-server-2008-r2, windows-services, enterprise-library

We are developing a windows service using c# .net v 4.5.1 which communicates with SQL database (SQL 2008 R2 x64), communication with SQL server is done using Enterprise Library data access block v 6, The windows service does a file copy process in bulk & updates the database about the status of file copy, it is observed that as soon as we start the service the number of connections get max out & we start receiving a "Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool.  This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached."

This issue is only observed when we run the code logic by deploying it as a windows service, When we run the exactly same code as a standalone exe (right click -> run as administrator) / non windows service, the connections on database are not exceeded & we do not receive the above mentioned error.

The code block which makes calls to the database is under the c# "using" statement, hence connection pooling should be handled by default.

Could you please recommend any suggestions on areas which I might have missed on to investigate this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you done so far?  Do you have a code sample?

Comment: not enough info.  how about showing some code...and the 'using statements' ?